# How do I upgrade "keras" from 1.2.0 to 2.0.0?

Tags: python, r, keras

I am running an image classifier but it keeps producing the error

> Keras loaded from keras Python module v1.2.0, however version 2.0.0 is required. Please update the keras Python package.
>   Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_format'

I have tried to remove and re-install keras through using python command ***"pip install keras --upgrade"*** and also through R using "***install.packages("keras")***" but all in vain.

Some one please advise me on how to get past that. When I try to update keras from python, it gives;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPH2v.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you try and upgrade keras? Any error messages?

Comment: @Sagaski, SO doesn't allow me to upload the error picture directly but the link is included in the question up!

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, Yes! I have Python27 & Python35

Comment: Trying removing the older one.

Comment: I just removed Python27! However, error keeps showing up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to uninstall the keras first:

```
pip uninstall keras
```

then install it :

```
pip install keras==version_number
```

Comment: Try using conda. Conda install keras.

Answer (score 1):

could you try mentioning the version number in the pip command

```
pip install Keras==2.0.0
```

Comment: the error message shows I have version 2.2.0. Please check the error picture included in the question

Comment: From the link(image), I could see some of the libraries are not compatible to upgrade keras=2.0.0. try with upgrading the requests,html5lib,bleach library version as mentioned.

Comment: the error still surfaces! even after loading the necessary versions for the respective modules

Comment: I can successfully able to install Keras==2.0.0 .problem with your setup is dependences version, try uninstalling all the dependences. check this link https://pastebin.com/wPcefsyx

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution was just bits from all the answers suggested down. So in this, I'm putting it all together.

I solved the problem by removing "Keras", "Keras-Applications" & "Keras-Preprocessing" from python as well as "Keras-2.1.6" from R.

I then re-installed "Keras" by ***pip install Keras==2.0.0*** then re-installed "Keras" in R also.

Now it runs perfectly.

Thanks, everyone for your contributions that threw light on the path to take!

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use python anaconda. you will get less errors and most of them can be easily solved.

here by looking image that you shared, it looks like problem is with versions of bleach, html5lib and google-gax, reinstall these dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

KERAS the Latest version. Released: Jun 24, 2020
pip install Keras==2.4.3

Comment: Please explain what you mean more clearly by your answer.